# add one more source to the repo manifest

Tags: yocto, repo

I need to build an image for a Xilinx FPGA. Followed [these directions](https://github.com/Xilinx/yocto-manifests). Everything worked and I managed to build it. Now I need to add an extra layer. I thought all I needed to do is to modify .`repo/manifests/default.xml` (add this layer, https://github.com/sbabic/meta-swupdate/tree/rocko) and then execute

`repo sync`

but I'm getting errors saying that changes to multitude of files will be overwritten by a checkout (these are the files that were built).

So how do I add a layer to my current environment and rebuild with a new layer without actually rebuilding the whole thing?

Answer (score 1):

```
cd ./sources/
git clone https://github.com/sbabic/meta-swupdate.git
cd ../conf/
vi ./bblayers.conf
add **{BSPDIR}/sources/meta-swupdate \** before (")
vi ./local.conf
add **IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " swupdate" **
bitbake
```

How to add Layer example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3HsaoVqX7dg